# Creating/Manipulating Elasticsearch Data View from filebeat.yml

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, dashboard, filebeat

I created some kibana dashboards and they are referencing to a kibana data view. This data view is currently default generated by Filebeat when i'm uploading the filebeat setup, etc. Therefore the data view gets a random Id and my dashboard gets a mising reference since those id's are changing. Now i want to configure somewhere the default created data view since my index- and template-pattern have fixed names and i could create a fixed data view. Then my Dashboards wouldn't go into "missing references". I searched the following sites:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-installation-configuration.html
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues

I created the Dashboards within the kibana UI and exported them for easier integration within my filebeat project.

My filebeat.yml file

```
# ============================== Filebeat modules ==============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

 
# ======================= Elasticsearch template setting =======================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1

setup.template.name: pac-filebeat-%{[agent.version]}
setup.template.pattern: pac-filebeat-%{[agent.version]}
setup.template.fields: ${path.config}/fields.yml



setup.dashboards.enabled: false
setup.dashboards.directory: ${path.config}\kibana\custom

# =================================== Kibana ===================================

# Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
setup.kibana:

  # Kibana Host
  # Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 5601)
  # In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:5601/path
  # IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:5601
  host: "localhost:5601"

# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

  # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
  protocol: "http"

  index: pac-filebeat-%{[agent.version]}

# ================================= Processors =================================
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~

# ================================== Logging ===================================
```

This is one example Dashboard.

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "description": "",
    "hits": 0,
    "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
      "searchSourceJSON": {
        "query": {
          "query": "",
          "language": "kuery"
        },
        "filter": []
      }
    },
    "optionsJSON": {
      "useMargins": true,
      "syncColors": false,
      "syncTooltips": false,
      "hidePanelTitles": false
    },
    "panelsJSON": [
      {
        "version": "8.5.3",
        "type": "lens",
        "gridData": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "w": 9,
          "h": 10,
          "i": "70779a3d-7880-416d-9736-8a374af8ae41"
        },
        "panelIndex": "70779a3d-7880-416d-9736-8a374af8ae41",
        "embeddableConfig": {
          "attributes": {
            "title": "",
            "visualizationType": "lnsLegacyMetric",
            "type": "lens",
            "references": [
              {
                "type": "index-pattern",
                "id": "454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d",
                "name": "indexpattern-datasource-layer-2a27a515-43d0-4aae-8764-467983de9faf"
              },
              {
                "type": "index-pattern",
                "name": "99c2853a-48e3-4042-badf-9c0829cec119",
                "id": "454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d"
              }
            ],
            "state": {
              "visualization": {
                "layerId": "2a27a515-43d0-4aae-8764-467983de9faf",
                "accessor": "10b01daf-1c3d-46d1-a014-b381ac70019c",
                "layerType": "data"
              },
              "query": {
                "query": "",
                "language": "kuery"
              },
              "filters": [
                {
                  "meta": {
                    "index": "99c2853a-48e3-4042-badf-9c0829cec119",
                    "alias": "pac.log.level : ERROR",
                    "type": "custom",
                    "key": "query",
                    "value": {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [],
                        "filter": [
                          {
                            "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                {
                                  "match": {
                                    "pac.log.level": "ERROR"
                                  }
                                }
                              ],
                              "minimum_should_match": 1
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "should": [],
                        "must_not": []
                      }
                    },
                    "disabled": false,
                    "negate": false
                  },
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [],
                      "filter": [
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "pac.log.level": "ERROR"
                                }
                              }
                            ],
                            "minimum_should_match": 1
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "should": [],
                      "must_not": []
                    }
                  },
                  "$state": {
                    "store": "appState"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "datasourceStates": {
                "indexpattern": {
                  "layers": {
                    "2a27a515-43d0-4aae-8764-467983de9faf": {
                      "columns": {
                        "10b01daf-1c3d-46d1-a014-b381ac70019c": {
                          "label": "Errors",
                          "customLabel": true,
                          "dataType": "number",
                          "operationType": "count",
                          "isBucketed": false,
                          "scale": "ratio",
                          "sourceField": "pac.log.level",
                          "filter": {
                            "query": "pac.log.level : ERROR",
                            "language": "kuery"
                          },
                          "params": {
                            "emptyAsNull": true
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "columnOrder": [
                        "10b01daf-1c3d-46d1-a014-b381ac70019c"
                      ],
                      "incompleteColumns": {}
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "internalReferences": [],
              "adHocDataViews": {}
            }
          },
          "enhancements": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "version": "8.5.3",
        "type": "lens",
        "gridData": {
          "x": 9,
          "y": 0,
          "w": 12,
          "h": 10,
          "i": "2bbc2f60-dfb2-4545-a725-9f9bec323e4b"
        },
        "panelIndex": "2bbc2f60-dfb2-4545-a725-9f9bec323e4b",
        "embeddableConfig": {
          "attributes": {
            "title": "",
            "visualizationType": "lnsXY",
            "type": "lens",
            "references": [
              {
                "type": "index-pattern",
                "id": "454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d",
                "name": "indexpattern-datasource-layer-a0f69cd9-6726-4551-9a91-cb330cf0b16d"
              }
            ],
            "state": {
              "visualization": {
                "legend": {
                  "isVisible": true,
                  "position": "right"
                },
                "valueLabels": "hide",
                "fittingFunction": "None",
                "xTitle": "",
                "yTitle": "",
                "axisTitlesVisibilitySettings": {
                  "x": false,
                  "yLeft": false,
                  "yRight": true
                },
                "tickLabelsVisibilitySettings": {
                  "x": true,
                  "yLeft": false,
                  "yRight": true
                },
                "labelsOrientation": {
                  "x": 0,
                  "yLeft": 0,
                  "yRight": 0
                },
                "gridlinesVisibilitySettings": {
                  "x": true,
                  "yLeft": false,
                  "yRight": true
                },
                "preferredSeriesType": "bar_horizontal_percentage_stacked",
                "layers": [
                  {
                    "layerId": "a0f69cd9-6726-4551-9a91-cb330cf0b16d",
                    "seriesType": "bar_horizontal_percentage_stacked",
                    "accessors": [
                      "cbf5323b-0d81-4411-afa3-91087f062874"
                    ],
                    "yConfig": [],
                    "layerType": "data",
                    "splitAccessor": "a98ba577-d539-4ab3-b798-2bddcb2efd3f",
                    "palette": {
                      "type": "palette",
                      "name": "status"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "query": {
                "query": "",
                "language": "kuery"
              },
              "filters": [],
              "datasourceStates": {
                "indexpattern": {
                  "layers": {
                    "a0f69cd9-6726-4551-9a91-cb330cf0b16d": {
                      "columns": {
                        "a98ba577-d539-4ab3-b798-2bddcb2efd3f": {
                          "label": "ESA states",
                          "dataType": "string",
                          "operationType": "terms",
                          "scale": "ordinal",
                          "sourceField": "pac.log.esa.connection",
                          "isBucketed": true,
                          "params": {
                            "size": 3,
                            "orderBy": {
                              "type": "column",
                              "columnId": "cbf5323b-0d81-4411-afa3-91087f062874"
                            },
                            "orderDirection": "desc",
                            "otherBucket": true,
                            "missingBucket": false,
                            "parentFormat": {
                              "id": "terms"
                            }
                          },
                          "customLabel": true
                        },
                        "cbf5323b-0d81-4411-afa3-91087f062874": {
                          "label": "Connected",
                          "dataType": "number",
                          "operationType": "unique_count",
                          "scale": "ratio",
                          "sourceField": "pac.log.esa.connection",
                          "isBucketed": false,
                          "filter": {
                            "query": "pac.log.esa.connection : Connected",
                            "language": "kuery"
                          },
                          "params": {
                            "emptyAsNull": true
                          },
                          "customLabel": true
                        }
                      },
                      "columnOrder": [
                        "a98ba577-d539-4ab3-b798-2bddcb2efd3f",
                        "cbf5323b-0d81-4411-afa3-91087f062874"
                      ],
                      "incompleteColumns": {}
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "internalReferences": [],
              "adHocDataViews": {}
            }
          },
          "enhancements": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "version": "8.5.3",
        "type": "lens",
        "gridData": {
          "x": 21,
          "y": 0,
          "w": 7,
          "h": 10,
          "i": "ef851b6b-222a-4b70-a7c3-ec6a85bdf4d1"
        },
        "panelIndex": "ef851b6b-222a-4b70-a7c3-ec6a85bdf4d1",
        "embeddableConfig": {
          "attributes": {
            "title": "",
            "visualizationType": "lnsLegacyMetric",
            "type": "lens",
            "references": [
              {
                "type": "index-pattern",
                "id": "454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d",
                "name": "indexpattern-datasource-layer-d8719702-b241-4931-8bd3-d706f1403c25"
              }
            ],
            "state": {
              "visualization": {
                "layerId": "d8719702-b241-4931-8bd3-d706f1403c25",
                "accessor": "312ded46-d0e9-4dcf-9779-b0ca10249a90",
                "layerType": "data"
              },
              "query": {
                "query": "",
                "language": "kuery"
              },
              "filters": [],
              "datasourceStates": {
                "indexpattern": {
                  "layers": {
                    "d8719702-b241-4931-8bd3-d706f1403c25": {
                      "columns": {
                        "312ded46-d0e9-4dcf-9779-b0ca10249a90": {
                          "label": "Failed DEO Executions",
                          "customLabel": true,
                          "dataType": "number",
                          "operationType": "count",
                          "isBucketed": false,
                          "scale": "ratio",
                          "sourceField": "pac.log.deo.status",
                          "filter": {
                            "query": "pac.log.deo.status : failed",
                            "language": "kuery"
                          },
                          "params": {
                            "emptyAsNull": true
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "columnOrder": [
                        "312ded46-d0e9-4dcf-9779-b0ca10249a90"
                      ],
                      "incompleteColumns": {}
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "internalReferences": [],
              "adHocDataViews": {}
            }
          },
          "enhancements": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "version": "8.5.3",
        "type": "lens",
        "gridData": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 10,
          "w": 14,
          "h": 11,
          "i": "7bcd2a3e-54c1-4b09-a0b6-d41c339c2ae6"
        },
        "panelIndex": "7bcd2a3e-54c1-4b09-a0b6-d41c339c2ae6",
        "embeddableConfig": {
          "attributes": {
            "title": "",
            "visualizationType": "lnsXY",
            "type": "lens",
            "references": [
              {
                "type": "index-pattern",
                "id": "454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d",
                "name": "indexpattern-datasource-layer-cd91feb0-0927-4465-b0fd-b5bac50af734"
              }
            ],
            "state": {
              "visualization": {
                "title": "Empty XY chart",
                "legend": {
                  "isVisible": true,
                  "position": "right",
                  "showSingleSeries": true
                },
                "valueLabels": "hide",
                "preferredSeriesType": "line",
                "layers": [
                  {
                    "layerId": "cd91feb0-0927-4465-b0fd-b5bac50af734",
                    "accessors": [
                      "8ccc17fc-529e-4460-9925-149e77e37dd1"
                    ],
                    "position": "top",
                    "seriesType": "line",
                    "showGridlines": false,
                    "layerType": "data",
                    "xAccessor": "43aa69d1-f806-4f87-a2b8-57718e85400a"
                  }
                ],
                "yTitle": "",
                "axisTitlesVisibilitySettings": {
                  "x": true,
                  "yLeft": false,
                  "yRight": true
                }
              },
              "query": {
                "query": "",
                "language": "kuery"
              },
              "filters": [],
              "datasourceStates": {
                "indexpattern": {
                  "layers": {
                    "cd91feb0-0927-4465-b0fd-b5bac50af734": {
                      "columns": {
                        "43aa69d1-f806-4f87-a2b8-57718e85400a": {
                          "label": "@timestamp",
                          "dataType": "date",
                          "operationType": "date_histogram",
                          "sourceField": "@timestamp",
                          "isBucketed": true,
                          "scale": "interval",
                          "params": {
                            "interval": "auto",
                            "includeEmptyRows": true,
                            "dropPartials": false
                          }
                        },
                        "8ccc17fc-529e-4460-9925-149e77e37dd1": {
                          "label": " System cpu usage",
                          "dataType": "number",
                          "operationType": "median",
                          "sourceField": "pac.log.system.monitor.cpu.pct",
                          "isBucketed": false,
                          "scale": "ratio",
                          "params": {
                            "emptyAsNull": true,
                            "format": {
                              "id": "percent",
                              "params": {
                                "decimals": 2
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "customLabel": true
                        }
                      },
                      "columnOrder": [
                        "43aa69d1-f806-4f87-a2b8-57718e85400a",
                        "8ccc17fc-529e-4460-9925-149e77e37dd1"
                      ],
                      "incompleteColumns": {}
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "internalReferences": [],
              "adHocDataViews": {}
            }
          },
          "enhancements": {}
        }
      }
    ],
    "timeRestore": false,
    "title": "ESA overview",
    "version": 1
  },
  "coreMigrationVersion": "8.5.3",
  "id": "d29c4ac0-ab68-11ed-bfcf-939f8111002e",
  "migrationVersion": {
    "dashboard": "8.5.0"
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "id": "454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d",
      "name": "70779a3d-7880-416d-9736-8a374af8ae41:indexpattern-datasource-layer-2a27a515-43d0-4aae-8764-467983de9faf",
      "type": "index-pattern"
    },
    {
      "id": "454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d",
      "name": "70779a3d-7880-416d-9736-8a374af8ae41:99c2853a-48e3-4042-badf-9c0829cec119",
      "type": "index-pattern"
    },
    {
      "id": "454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d",
      "name": "2bbc2f60-dfb2-4545-a725-9f9bec323e4b:indexpattern-datasource-layer-a0f69cd9-6726-4551-9a91-cb330cf0b16d",
      "type": "index-pattern"
    },
    {
      "id": "454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d",
      "name": "ef851b6b-222a-4b70-a7c3-ec6a85bdf4d1:indexpattern-datasource-layer-d8719702-b241-4931-8bd3-d706f1403c25",
      "type": "index-pattern"
    },
    {
      "id": "454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d",
      "name": "7bcd2a3e-54c1-4b09-a0b6-d41c339c2ae6:indexpattern-datasource-layer-cd91feb0-0927-4465-b0fd-b5bac50af734",
      "type": "index-pattern"
    },
    {
      "id": "c6a11f70-ab68-11ed-bfcf-939f8111002e",
      "name": "tag-c6a11f70-ab68-11ed-bfcf-939f8111002e",
      "type": "tag"
    }
  ],
  "type": "dashboard",
  "updated_at": "2023-02-13T07:14:45.551Z",
  "version": "WzE1NTI1NiwzMl0="
}
```

This would be the used tag inside the above dashboard

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "color": "#52bc22",
    "description": "",
    "name": "custom"
  },
  "coreMigrationVersion": "8.5.3",
  "id": "c6a11f70-ab68-11ed-bfcf-939f8111002e",
  "migrationVersion": {
    "tag": "8.0.0"
  },
  "references": [],
  "type": "tag",
  "updated_at": "2023-02-13T07:39:07.543Z",
  "version": "WzE1NTM0NywzMl0="
}
```

The error message:

```
error dashboard asset: returned 200 to import file: 1 error: error: missing_references, asset ID=d29c4ac0-ab68-11ed-bfcf-939f8111002e; asset type=dashboard; references=[{Type:index-pattern ID:454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d} {Type:index-pattern ID:454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d} {Type:index-pattern ID:454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d} {Type:index-pattern ID:454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d} {Type:index-pattern ID:454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d}]. Response: {"successCount":1,"success":false,"warnings":[],"successResults":[{"type":"tag","id":"c6a11f70-ab68-11ed-bfcf-939f8111002e","meta":{"title":"custom","icon":"tag"},"overwrite":true}],"errors":[{"id":"d29c4ac0-ab68-11ed-bfcf-939f8111002e","type":"dashboard","meta":{"title":"ESA overview","icon":"dashboardApp"},"error":{"type":"missing_references","references":[{"type":"index-pattern","id":"454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d"},{"type":"index-pattern","id":"454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d"},{"type":"index-pattern","id":"454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d"},{"type":"index-pattern","id":"454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d"},{"type":"index-pattern","id":"454f0a8e-d5b8-4c8d-9dbe-a1a61782d24d"}]},"overwrite":true}]}
```

kind regardes

Comment: Need more information to help, for example what is your index pattern? Please add screenshot to understand your request clearly.

Comment: Done. I hope this is now enough information. If not please let me now what more you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure Filebeat to [use your own dashboard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-dashboards.html) using the following settings:

- `setup.dashboards.url`
- `setup.dashboards.file`
- `setup.dashboards.index`
- `setup.dashboards.string_replacements` (<-- probably the one you're looking for)

Comment: Thank you. dashboards.index was the one i was looking for. Best regards